CrossSim crossbar simulator Adding new device
There are re-ram and synaptic tfts that I want to simulate using CrossSim, but in CrossSim documentation it is not well explained what the set.csv and reset.csv means. Help me out, which values do I need to take from my devices.
enter image description here
Here's whats available in set.csv
read voltage is taken as 0.1 V

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
